# Validate multiple textareas on submit before post to mysql

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to check multiple textareas if empty before I can write any data in a mysql db.
The form is generated dynamically and I don't know the id/name of the textareas.

Form with multiple, dynamic generated textareas, id and names generated dynamically as well:

```
<form action=\"$self\" method=\"POST\" id=\"daily_frm\"  enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">   
 <table border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"2\" id=\"tb_daily\" class=\"tb_daily\" width=\"100%\">
  <tr>
  <th scope=\"col\" id=\"col_stn\">Station</th>
  <th scope=\"col\" id=\"col_comm\">Comment</th>
  <th scope=\"col\" id=\"qcif\">QCIF</th>
  <th scope=\"col\" id=\"attach\">Attachment</th>
 </tr>"; 

while ($stn_b = mysql_fetch_array($station_b)){
  print "<tr>
           <td>$stn_b[station]</td>
           <td><textarea id=\"$stn_b[station]_comment\" cols=\"60\" rows=\"5\" value=\"\"></textarea></td>
           <td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"$stn_b[station]_qcif\" value=\"1\"/></td>
          <td><input id=\"$stn_b[station]_attach\" type=\"file\" />
        </tr>       
        ";
}

print"
<tr><td colspan=\"4\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" name=\"submit_daily\" id=\"submit_daily\"><input type=\"reset\" name=\"clear_daily\" value=\"Clear\"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

My approach to check if any textarea is empty when clicking the submit button:

```
<script type='application/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#daily_frm').submit( function () {
     $('#daily_frm textarea').each(function(){
     if ($(this).val()==='') {

    alert($(this).attr('id') + ' field is empty');
    $(this).focus();
    return false;

   }
 });
    });
});
```

I get the alert box with the corresponding textarea name.

My php code to write everything into the db:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_daily'])){

while ($stn_b = mysql_fetch_array($station_b)){
    $s = $stn_b['station'];
    $sid = $stn_b['idtb_station'];

    $daily_comment = addslashes($_POST[$s."_comment"]);


    if(!empty($_POST[$s."_qcif"])) {
        $qcif = $_POST[$s."_qcif"];
        echo "$qcif<br />"; 
    }   else {
        $qcif = "0";
    }


    $post_daily_sql = "INSERT INTO tb_daily tb_station_idtb_station,date,author,comment,upload) VALUES ('$sid','$today','$user','$daily_comment','$qcif')"; 
}   
}
```

My problem now is that in case of an empty textarea I'll get the alert box, but my script still continues with trying to write into the db (I know the php/mysql part is not complete).
Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#daily_frm').submit( function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var errCount = 0;
        $('#daily_frm textarea').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val()==='') {
                alert($(this).attr('id') + ' field is empty');
                $(this).focus();
                errCount++;
            }
        });
        if( errCount > 0 ) {
            reutrn false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```